# Error expecting statement at the beginning of endforeach statement

Tags: php

I am running the following code am getting the error expecting statement at the beginning  of endforeach statement.

```
<?php foreach($lessons as $lesson) ; ?>
    <h1><?=$lesson;  ?></h1>
<?php endforeach ;?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php foreach($lessons as $lesson) ; ?>
                                   ^ should be a :
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php foreach($lessons as $lesson) ?>

  <h1> <?php=$lesson;  ?></h1>
```

No
    `; or :` is required

Similar eg:-

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <?php 
    $colors = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow"); 

    foreach ($colors as $value) {
       echo "$value <br>";
    }
    ?>   

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

fthe format should be like this. `foreach():`

```
<?php foreach($lessons as $lesson):?>
   <h1><?=$lesson; ?></h1>
<?php endforeach ;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of constantly switching between PHP and HTML, why not write it like this :-

```
<?php

foreach($lessons as $lesson) { echo "<h1>$lesson</h1>"; }

?>
```